# Is it true that all nouns must be able to accept a が particle and a を particle?

Tags: grammar, particles, adjectives, syntax

Is it true that all nouns must be able to accept a が particle and a を particle?

I was curious about how we could form a sentence with:

1. 特別が
2. 特別を
3. 出色が
4. 出色を

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nouns can always take the particles を and が. 形容動詞 cannot take these particles *unless* they are also classified as 名詞. As far as I know, neither 出色 or 特別 are independently-functioning nouns in standard grammar. One way you can check is by googling the exact phrase "特別を", for example. If hits are low, or if you get hits with 特別 set off from the を by quote marks, brackets etc. (for example, 「特別」を訳す, translate *the word* "特別"), the odds are good that you can't use it. That said, people will use language as is their wont, and there are some legit hits for 特別を. That does not mean it is standard, correct usage, and will not give you license to use it.

There are some na-adj. that are also nouns. 安全なところ, a safe place; 安全を守る, observe safety.

Additionally, some na-adj. can be converted into nouns by adding the suffix さ　to them. 静かな街, a quiet street; 街の静かさ, the stillness of the street. You can google these to test them as well.

Comment: +1 for the Google test, but I think the inherently subjective nature of what is "correct" becomes quite relevant here.

Comment: What is tricky about these examples is that they allow genitive case: `特別の`.

Comment: @ Matt - True dat, but you can't learn if there aren't rules. I know I don't feel like I'm 自在　enough to muck about and go all Joycean on 標準語's ass.

Comment: @rdb the question here is how do we check for sure whether a 形容動詞 is also an independently-functioning noun? The googling part sounds cool but its limitations are great (for example, like some words are already seldom used or perhaps seldom used in writing.. so they will already have low hits etc). so some words we can add the さ suffix while some we can't, but how od we know if we can? Is there a dictionary that we can trust (because they tend to contradict each other)?

Comment: As Matt has noted, the idea of what "correct" usage is flexible and ever-changing, and, as Axioplase has noted, various authoritative sources will differ. To know "for sure" is probably not what you need. To know how words are normally used is enough, and I think you will be surprised how useful Google is in that regard.

Comment: I'm actually not sure what do you mean when you say Google is useful in that regard. For one thing, i search for `"出色が"` and have 1380 results. scanning through the first page we have `出色がある`, `出色が違うし`, `出色がよく、`出色が良くなるように` etc. `"出色を"` has 671 results, examples: `出色を持ちます`, `出色を感動させる`, `出色を失う`, `出色を見てみたい`. from those results, are we to conclude that it is ok to use 出色 as a noun ? or is it that since the count 600+ 1300+ is pretty low, we can conclude that 出色 can be used as a noun, but not in formal situations?

Comment: You have to think for yourself here and make a judgment. To me, yes, those hit counts are low enough that I would hesitate to use 出色 as a noun myself. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @rdb ok thx for the help =D

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems obvious and weirdly asked.

1. A noun does not "accept" a particle.
2. A noun can *always* be the object or the subject of a sentence.

Trivial examples "Nounが名詞です" and "Nounを習った".
A few less trivial examples, just for the sake of it:

> 特別が普通より良い

Special is better than common (à la "less is more")

> 特別を普通にしたい

I want to make special things common (as a progressive architect may say)

> 自然な例文と引きやすさに出色がある

There is excellency in the natural examples and in the 引きやすさ.
(Example drawn from http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/三宅徳嘉)

> 出色を英訳すると、どうなりますか

How do you translate 出色 in English?

Comment: I think that perhaps Pacerier is asking about these two terms in particular because many dictionaries do not list them as nouns, only as "na adjectives", so that 特別を普通にする and 出色がある would be ungrammatical. Actual usage of these words is starting to go beyond the limits described by the dictionaries though, albeit often as self-conscious language play/"implied quotative" use (e.g. Google 特別が and see how many examples put quotes around the 特別, acknowledging the use as unconventional). Similar phenomena can be observed for other word types: "うれしいを、しっかり"; "知るを楽しむ", etc.

Comment: @matt Edict shows them as nouns.  I know that my last example is cheating using implicit quotes, but I think the others are fair, provided I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Edict may be more progressive on this issue, it no doubt depends on the dictionary. I have no problem with your examples -- just pointing out that some authorities might consider them nonstandard. I think it is the gap between these authorities and actual usage in certain idiolects that inspired the question here.

Comment: Your ‘trivial’ examples seem to ignore the [use–mention distinction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use-mention_distinction).

Comment: @zhen: does it not emphasising the nouns make them less nouns?  Grammatically speaking, isn't still a good answer?

Comment: The point is, ‘word’ and ‘“word”’ mean different things. The quoted one is a name for a word, and the unquoted one is a name for a thing. So in some sense, they are different words.

Comment: @zhen I acknowledge the difference, but I wonder whether it affects the answer, since I think both 'foo' and '*foo*' are nouns.

Comment: Put Zhen’s comment differently, you can even say 美しいを英訳するとどうなりますか, but this does not mean that を can be attached to an i-adjective.