# 「を大好き」と「が大好き」の違いは何ですか？

Tags: grammar, usage, particles, particle-が, particle-を

What's the difference in usage and meaning when using を with 大好き or 好き versus using が? I would think that using が is stating that the subject that you are talking about is loved, while using を is suggesting that they are being loved, despite the fact that 好き is an adjective, not a verb. However, I read elsewhere that using を is actually less strong. What's the difference?

Comment: I'm by no means a native speaker, but を大好き sounds really weird to me, although I've seen it sometimes. However, nobody seems to say を大好きだ. Why? Is it because it makes the を too obviously wrong, as copulas clearly don't take objects?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but a native speaker I know said that he says を.

Comment: possible duplicate of [を vs が with use against 好き?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/%e3%82%92-vs-%e3%81%8c-with-use-against-%e5%a5%bd%e3%81%8d)

Comment: I don't quite understand the answer to that one, although it certainly is the same question. I haven't heard を used with思う, I don't think-I think I've only heard it with と.

Comment: を is used with both suki and omou

Comment: Why is it used with 好き！

Comment: I'm not happy with this being closed as a duplicate because I don't feel sawa's answer addresses when this is used or what the difference in meaning is.  It just says that it's ungrammatical, but this question doesn't ask whether it's grammatical--it asks about a difference in meaning.  We should only close as duplicate when the answer on the other question addresses this one too.

Answer (score 5):

The important difference is the fact that using が is correct by anyone's standards and using を is only correct by certain people's standards.  We may have been using the latter for decades now (and I admit that many native speakers do) but how significant is that against the whole history of our language?

Point is there are people who use only が with 好き and those who use both が and を, but I do not think there are people who only use を.  It is as though we knew intrinsically which one was "more" correct originally.

My own stance is that any grammar discussion on this matter is doomed to failure as anyone can instantly collect millions of examples for either camp online, so I will talk about the difference between the two.

As OP mentioned, using が would tend to express a stronger liking than using を.  If you used が in telling someone that you like him/her, you would be likely to sound more serious. If you used を, you COULD possibly end up sounding a little bit capricious if not necessarily flirtatious.  Needless to say, though, the other person would not make a hasty decision based solely on a single particle choice by you.  Everything else you say will count just as much or even more.

Comment: As 好き is derived from the transitive verb 好【す】く, I think its usage with を would be far more common when compared "against the whole history of our language".

Comment: I am among the `people who use only が with 好き`.

Comment: Why do people use を though?

Answer (score 0):

Found this on a search: https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1345796783

### In a nutshell

According to that answer, using を where が is generally considered "correct" Japanese (as in the cases of 好き, 嫌い, 欲しい, できる, 食べたい, etc.), is "New Tokyo dialect". As far as を好き and が好き are concerned, it's said that there's no difference in meaning.