# Is it okay to say 日本語を好き?

Tags: word-choice, particle-が, particle-を

I saw that is correct to use が but I can't understand the differences between を and が

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17857/5010

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/%E3%82%92%E5%A4%A7%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D-%E3%81%A8-%E3%81%8C%E5%A4%A7%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D-%E3%81%AE%E9%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that "suki" is an adjectival-noun (the set of nouns which are closer in meaning to our adjectives, but function grammatically more like nouns). It stands in place of the English "to like", which is a verb -- hence the confusion.

If it helps, try thinking about "suki" as meaning "an enjoyable-to-Subject thing" rather than "I like [x]".

Comment: There are actually some grammatical contexts where all speakers accept 〇〇を好き（だ）. Also, there are some speakers who accept it in all grammatical contexts.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be most acceptable when it's buried in a subclause.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know wether this is grammatically correct or not, but I would never say it, but I think :

> 日本語を好きになる

Sounds very natural, even though it doesn't really mean :

> 日本語が好きだ