# Why is に used in 若者が元気に溢れている?

Tags: grammar, syntax, particle-に

Why is に used in a sentence like this?

> 若者が元気**に**溢れている

I thought it was:

> 若者に元気**が**溢れている

I know に is used as an indirect object marker.
Could someone tell me the difference between direct and indirect object?

---

I already understand this usage of the particle:

It is used to show destination of an action

> 本を彼に上げた

To show an action in a place with semi-permanent or permanent consequences

> 山に雪が積もった

To show existence in a place

> 部屋にいる

To show a specific time when something happens

> 来た時に林檎を食べた

To show the agent in passive or verbs of receiving

> ペンを彼に貰った
>   林檎が彼に食べられた

Comment: Could you edit the question to focus on the example at the end?  Right now you're asking for a list of all the dozens of ways to use に, but for that you'd be better served by looking at a dictionary entry.  A question about this particular example should be fine, though :-)

Comment: I changed the question, is it ok?

Comment: I think it's a lot better now, after your edit and mirka's edit :-)

Answer (score 5):

You are understanding `に` correctly. This is actually a quirk of the verb 溢れる. It can be used with either a subject (〜が) or with an object (〜に/〜で).

#### 元気 as subject

> 若者に元気**が**溢れている
>   *元気 is overflowing in the 若者*

#### 元気 as object

> 若者が元気**に**溢れている
>   *若者 is overflowing with 元気*

Just remember that when you are talking about something that is overflowing *literally* and not figuratively, you should put it as a subject:

- コップから水**が**溢れている *Water is overflowing from the cup*
- コップが水**に**溢れている ← unnatural

---

There are other verbs like this that can be used both ways, for example:

- 満ちる → 月**が**満ちる / (心が)喜び**に**満ちる
- 欠ける → 歯**が**欠ける / (彼は)常識**に**欠ける

Comment: When does が mark the direct object? I know it does with potential of verb like 好き　嬉しい... Are there other cases. Also Can you explain how is に used as an indirect complement? For example here:マフィアは隠れ蓑に合法的な事業を展開している。I would have used として since 隠れ蓑に is not the recipient of an action.

Comment: @Splikie Those are good questions, but unfortunately I think they require explanations that are too long for a comment. The 隠れ蓑 example is pretty interesting. You might want to post them as separate questions :)

Comment: @Splikie Sorry, I made a huge mistake about the `が` usage. I meant subject, not direct object.

Comment: With some verb it does mark the Direct object though. 僕に新聞が読める　僕は貴方が好き　僕にはその本の内容が分かる

Comment: @Splikie That's true. I'm not so sure anymore! If my answer is terribly off-base, hopefully someone will point it out or post a better answer…

Comment: There is such a thing as が-marked objects (called "nominative objects" in the literature). I write briefly about them here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26005/usage-of-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%92%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D-outside-of-embedded-clauses/27367#27367