# に as an indirect complement

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-に

From this question

[Why is に used in 若者が元気に溢れている?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29460/why-is-%E3%81%AB-used-in-%E8%8B%A5%E8%80%85%E3%81%8C%E5%85%83%E6%B0%97%E3%81%AB%E6%BA%A2%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B)

I did few hours ago another one, a bigger one arose.

> マフィアは隠れ蓑に合法的な事業を展開している

I know に can be used as an indirect complement but I would have used として since 隠れ蓑に is not the recipient of an action.

Also Can someone explain how is に used as an indirect complement?

Comment: Think of it as meaning "for". Such uses of indirect complements (datives) are found throughout many languages, here is another one for example: "cui bono"

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that you can use `として` there. This kind of `〜に` basically means として. I'm not sure you can call it a complement though, because according to the definitions I just looked up, it seems more like an adjunct. But terminology is not my forté, so I'll just give some examples of the same kind of usage.

- (私は)息抜き**に**本を読む → I 本を読む as a 息抜き
- (私は)暇つぶし**に**テレビを見る → I テレビを見る as a 暇つぶし
- (私は)東京を拠点**に**活動する → I 活動する with [ 東京 as the 拠点 ]
- (私たちは)結婚を前提**に**付き合う → We 付き合う with [ 結婚 as a 前提 ]

The `に` in the above examples can all be replaced with `として`.

For many of the words that are often used adverbially like 試しに (試しに買った) or 戯れに (戯れに描いた), you can't replace the `に` with `として` because those are set phrases. But the meaning of the `に` is basically the same as として.

Answer (score 1):

So yesterday I was trying to understand this a little better.
I think that に is just the answer japanese has to most of the indirect compliments.

There are Transitive and Intransitive verbs

---

**Transitive verbs** have

Subject=The one who performs the action
Direct Object=The one which the action acts upon
Verb=An action

> 僕が林檎を食べる

How do you know which is the direct object?
You could ask this questions:

> What is the action?
>   Who/What is doing the action?
>   What is being (insert verb)?

So the answers are

> What is the action?  食べる
>   Who/What is doing the action? 僕  (Marked with が)
>   What is being (食べる )?林檎 (Marked with を)

Sometimes there is a receiver of the direct object:
**The indirect object**

> 僕が彼にペンを上げた
>
> What is the action?  上げる
>   Who/What is doing the action? 僕
>   What is being (上げる)?ペン
>   Who is recipient of the Object?彼

**This indirect object is marked with に**

In my example

> マフィアは隠れ蓑に合法的な事業を展開している
>
> What is the action?  展開する
>   Who/What is doing the action? マフィア
>   What is being (展開する)?合法的な事業
>   Who is recipient of the Object?隠れ蓑

You can say that 隠れ蓑 is the recipient of the action but you can say that it answer the te question

> as what?

Which is another indirect complement.
So as long as there is no other particle that fit the role に can be used. (IF there is a choice you can use another particle which fit the same gramatical role in that situation, but not with the complement of means で)

---

**Intransitive verbs**

**Here there is no direct object for the action** 
Excluding times when:
You get out of a smaller to a bigger place:

> 建物を出る

You are going trough something

> 空を飛んでいる

So some verbs have a transitive and intransitive form.

The transitive is used to act upon an object and the intransitive is kinda like a state of being.

> Transitive:閉める=To close something
>   Intransitive:閉まる=To be closed

Some verbs while being intransitive have different meanings. For example:

Intransitive:映える=To shine, To look attractive, To look pretty

映える=To shine

**If the meaning is active** (The subject is doing an action)
You have something like this:

> 夕焼けが空に映える
>
> What is the action?  映える
>   Who/What is doing the action? 夕焼け
>   What is being (映える)? Nothing
>   Where is the verb happening?空
>
> The sunset shines in the sky

As you can see に here means the location where something takes place.

If the meaning is passive (in the sense that something is doing a state for a lack of a better term).
映える=To look attractive

> ジャケットが映えるように三角筋と僧帽筋を鍛える.
>
> What is the action?  映える
>   Who/What is doing the action? ジャケット
>   What is being (映える)? Nothing
>   What is the indirect complement? Nothing
>
> In order for a jacket to look attractive you have to train your deltoids and traps.

When I say **indirect complement** I mean the answer to every question which is not "Whom?" "What?". (that is how it is my native language at least).

- It can used to also mean the way you do something when transforming な adjectives into adverbs.
- It can be used to show company

and has other roles.

Ultimately I think it does not matter the distinction beetween intransitive (active and passive) since I believe you could say, but I am not sure so if there is a mistake please correct me.

> 僕がジャケットに映えるように三角筋と僧帽筋を鍛える.
>   I,in order to look good in a jacket, train my deltoids and traps.
>
> 僕にジャケットが映えるように三角筋と僧帽筋を鍛える.
>   In order for the jacket to look good on me, I train my deltoids and traps.

If I am wrong please correct me.