# Should it be が大好き or を大好き?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-が, particle-を

I am very new to Japanese language and I am now kind of addicted to learning this beautiful language and the culture.

Just a question I want to ask is:

Which one of the below one is right?

> 私はゴルフ**が**大好きです

or

> 私はゴルフ**を**大好きです

Any help will be greatly appreciated from the heart.

Comment: Also see http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26005/1628 and the linked questions there.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike in English 大好 is not a verb so it cannot take the object particle を ([usually](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26005/usage-of-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%92%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D-outside-of-embedded-clauses)). 大好 is a na-adjective, so your first sentence is the correct one.

In case it wasn't just a typo, note that I corrected your question. The object particle is を (wo) not お (o).

Answer (score 0):

私はゴルフが大好きです is right.

If you want to use を, "私はゴルフをすることが大好きです" is good.