# What does 彼女は私ほど自分のことを好きじゃない mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

Consider the following

> 彼女は私ほど自分のことを好きじゃない。

My attempt is as follows

- A: She does not love herself as much as I love myself.
- B: She does not love herself as much as she loves me.
- C: She does not love herself as much as I love her.
- D: She does not love me as much as I love myself.
- E: She does not love me as much as I love her.

Which is the correct translation?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out **how** you think it conveys the second meaning in your list. I **do** understand if you can't tell whether 自分 refers to "Me myself" or "they themselves".  Also, a more accurate translation of 相手 here would be "the other person", "he/she/they", etc.

Comment: Just for the record, you always put up interesting sentences on your questions!

Comment: BTW I feel this [～を好き](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26005/5010) is totally acceptable :)

Comment: do you have any context for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sentences A–D are all possible interpretations, but practically it's either A or C. Without any context, I personally feel the likelihood is as follows: `A > C >> B ≒ D >> E ≒ 0`

I feel E is nearly impossible because 自分 is referring to different two people which are not "herself" nor "myself".

Answer (score 4):

Seems like it can be interpreted in 2-3 ways, but the way I understood it after my first read was.

> She doesn't love herself as much as I love her.

After reading the sentence like a 100 more times, I came to believe that by reading between the lines a little.

> She does not love me as much as I love her.

Could also be quite possible. It also seems like the most probable thing you might wanna say to someone.(comparing how much one loves oneself is kinda weird no?).

Either way, they all feel somewhat possible to some degree. Just a little context could change everything. Not sure where you got that sentence though.

Answer (score -2):

Let me correct your sentence first, it should have been" 彼女は私ほど自分のこと**が**好きじゃない。". "好き”is an adjective in japanese ,so you have to use"**が**before it.
my answers are A and B, it can be understood in both ways

Comment: を好き (and を嫌い) is not gramatically incorrect in modern Japanese, although it is more natural in some cases than others. The comments to the original question show native speaker @naruto claiming the sentence sounds fine.