# What's wrong with my sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm constantly practicing and creating new japanese phrases in my head, so far it has been easy to speak it, although without a computer it's hard to write the alphabets, I get confused with all the Kanjis, Hiragana and Katakana, I do know how to distinguish them but sometimes I can't read them, especially the Kanjis, therefore, I wrote this sentence and I'd like to know if it was correct.

> 明日私達は映画をみる私はみきーちゃんを好きですでもみきーちゃんは私をすきじゃない。
>   Tomorrow we'll watch a movie, I like Miki-chan but Miki-chan doesn't like me.

About this sentence I'd like to know if I can put another は instead of でも, I heard that I can use は to emphasize the phrase following it. Is it correct?

Comment: Your English sentence is poorly constructed to begin with.  What does watching a movie have to do with you liking someone or someone not liking you?

Comment: @l'électeur I didn't create the sentence thinking in english but in japanese. I'm sorry if it's sounds out of context but imagine I'm texting a friend that Miki and I we'll watch a movie and I like her but she doesn't like me... Simple as that :D

Comment: It doesn't sound out of context, to me. It is two sentences, but you didn't indicate that with punctuation. That's kind of a red flag. Learning a new language requires comprehension of at least the basic grammatical concepts such as sentences and clauses

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to know if I can put another は instead of でも

No, you can't. でも is a conjunction (like "however" in English). は is a particle, which determines the role of the phrase that *precedes* it. They are grammatically different, and is never interchangeable.

I'm not sure what you've actually heard about "は for emphasis". Perhaps you've just heard about contrastive-*wa*?

---

Other comments:

- Use Japanese commas and periods appropriately.
- Don't mix polite form (～です/～ます) in the middle of the text written in plain form. It looks more strange than you might imagine.
- What's the horizontal bar between みき and ちゃん for? Is it intended to be a hyphen? Such a long bar means a long vowel marker (i.e., it turns "Mi-ki" into "Mi-kee") in Japanese. You should omit that bar.

Corrected version:

> 明日私達は映画をみる。私はみきちゃんを好きだ。でもみきちゃんは私をすきじゃない。

Comment: May I say that I thought about changing the です to だ? But I thought it was wrong because I wasn't sure if 好き was a な-adjective... One question that I have is if the commas and periods are used the same way as in english? When should I place them preferably? After a verb, after a thought?

Comment: I thought that we should put a **ー** between the name and *chan, san, kun, sama, etc...*. Is this an hyphen? Should I use it just like in english?

Comment: ちなみに「を好き」については多少不安があって調べたんですが、間違ってもいないようです。 https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1345796783

Comment: @keithmaxx まあ間違いでもないのでしょうが、指摘したほうがよかったですね… https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26005/5010