# Do the following, and similar sentences, work grammatically?

Tags: particle-が

Just the title basically.

> 私の家族の中で私の母が料理が一番上手です。
>
> 私の家族の中で私が私の父が一番好きです。

Thank you for any, and all, help!

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the point of the question, are you asking about the validity of sentences with multiple がs in it? Or is something else the focus?

Comment: I suppose that would be part of it, yes. Along with the way the superlative has been used.

Comment: Roger, thanks. (“superlative”=最上級形容詞=この「一番」の使用は正しいのかとのこと)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, both sentences are grammatically correct and perfectly understandable. One thing that looks weird to me is 私の before 母/父, which is redundant and *should* be omitted. In Japanese, you should use 私の only when it is necessary to avoid confusion. The 私の at the beginning of the sentence is usually unnecessary, too.

- (私の)家族の中で母が料理が一番上手です。
- (私の)家族の中で私が父が一番好きです。

In addition, in order to avoid two が's, people probably tend to say 家族の中で私が父**を**一番好きです more often in the latter case. See: [Usage of ～を好き outside of embedded clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26005/5010)