# How would I translate "someone who likes (something)" into Japanese?

Tags: grammar, syntax

The specific sentence that came up when I was practicing with my study buddy today was, "Do you know anyone who likes sports?"

My best guess was:

> だれかスポーツが好きな人を知っていますか？

But since 好き is an adjective, not a verb, I'm not sure if I can put things together that way. Thanks for reading!

Comment: I don't know if this counts as an answer, but the sentence you came up with is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with sbkgs4686 that your translation is great. Sometimes thinking about slightly different forms and examining the difference in nuances can be a worthwhile exercise, here are some:

> だれかスポーツを好きな人を知っていますか？

が is often used when the context refers to one thing and you are trying to talk about something else. 「僕の友達に料理の好きな人がいるんだけどさ」「スポーツが好きな人は知っていますか？」

> スポーツ好きなやつ知らない？

Much more informal and therefore it conveys the closeness appropriate and desirable among close friends.

Comment: That's very interesting. I seldom encounter the pattern　〜を好きな〜 compared to 〜がすきな〜. I do understand that 好き is an adjective. Are there other adjectives that follow this pattern?

Comment: @rebuuilt [Usage of 〜を好き outside of embedded clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26005/usage-of-～を好き-outside-of-embedded-clauses)