# Can を be use instead of が?

Tags: particles

I've heard that を is sometimes used instead of が nowadays. Although it is strictly incorrect it is becoming more common. Is this true ?

For example:

お茶を好きです

車を欲しいです

Answer (score 2):

This article by 東山篤規 is exactly about this topic: [助詞「が」と「を」の置換性について ─文例と世代の比較─](http://www.ritsumei.ac.jp/acd/cg/lt/rb/599/599pdf/higasiya.pdf) The following table illustrates を is preferred by younger generations in some contexts. The dagger (†/‡) in the rightmost column indicates a statistically significant difference between the two generations.

[image]

Roughly speaking, younger people tend to prefer を with できる, 欲しい, ～たい, ～(ら)れる and so on, especially in relatively complex sentences. I personally feel 私は車を欲しいです is a little unnatural (私は車が欲しいです sounds much better), but 車を欲しい人を探す and 車を欲しくなる映画 somehow sounds fine.

Although not included in this table, I think the same tendency is found also with 好き, 嫌い, etc. Still, a simple sentence like お茶を好きです is considered wrong regardless of the generation.

Related:

- [Usage of ～を好き outside of embedded clauses](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/26005/5010)
- [The difference between が and を with the potential form of a verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/609/5010)

Comment: That's an excellent article, very interesting. Can you recommend a resource or site for finding such free articles on Japanese linguistics?

Comment: @kandyman Unfortunately I know nothing better than simple google search. Snailplane [introduced](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26005/usage-of-%ef%bd%9e%e3%82%92%e5%a5%bd%e3%81%8d-outside-of-embedded-clauses#comment56278_26005) this article to me :)