# Why is it possible to use を好き?

Tags: grammar

> 「……だが駄目だ。私はシンと出会ってしまった。私は愛を知ってしまった。シンのいない世界に意味などなく、シンのいない人生に価値などない。——精霊たちのこと**を好き**というのも、偽らざる真実だ。けれど、シンと再び出会うためなら、私はその全てを捨てることができる」

Why is it possible to use を好き rather than the normal が好き in this context, grammatically? I know usually を好き is a wrong expression.

Comment: Have you seen this question and the links in it? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26005/usage-of-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%92%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D-outside-of-embedded-clauses

Comment: Yes. So を好き is possible because of the という?

Comment: I think so, but it's way too subtle for me. Best to edit your question if you want more information.

Comment: Another related question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/77907/can-%E3%82%92-bAnother related question:

Answer (score 2):

Generally, this kind of phenomenon seems to be called 格の交替 in Japanese linguistics.

中上級を教える人のための日本語文法ハンドブック says this happens (p185)

> 1. 出来事を描く立場が変わる場合
> 2. 出来事の状態的な側面を描く場合

1 is the one that happens by changing active/passive. Your case is (probably) included in 2.

If you google a keyword like "ヲ格　ガ格 交替", then you see lots of research articles - so it is beyond my knowledge to give a comprehensive answer.

The following are the を/が examples with 好きだ

1. 私は甘いものが好きだ I like sweets
2. 私が甘いものを好きだということを彼は知らない He doesn't know that I like sweets.

Maybe it is not exactly about 出来事の状態的な側面, but I feel 1 and 2 have difference of perspectives.

- 1 says something about *sweets* so 甘いもの is treated like a subject (= use of が)
- 2 says something about *I* (due to the enclosing by ということ), so that 甘いもの is treated as an object and 私 as the subject.