# Why is を used instead of が in the following sentence?

Tags: particles

While translating Kanzaki Iori's song '命に嫌われている', I've found strange the following sentence:
...誰かを嫌うこともファッションで...
Isn't が used in sentences like "I like/hate sth"? Please explain why here it is like this.
Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/%e3%82%92%e5%a4%a7%e5%a5%bd%e3%81%8d-%e3%81%a8-%e3%81%8c%e5%a4%a7%e5%a5%bd%e3%81%8d-%e3%81%ae%e9%81%95%e3%81%84%e3%81%af%e4%bd%95%e3%81%a7%e3%81%99%e3%81%8b https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26005/usage-of-%ef%bd%9e%e3%82%92%e5%a5%bd%e3%81%8d-outside-of-embedded-clauses

Comment: Although I think you should look at the linked posts as well, 嫌う is a verb while 嫌い is an adj. These are two different words.

Comment: Opps. I wasn't paying enough attention. Good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 誰か**を嫌う**

[嫌]{きら}う is a transitive verb. 「XXを嫌う」 is a correct way to say "hate XX". You don't say 「XXが嫌う」 to mean that. I think you're confusing it with the na-adjective 「(～が/を)嫌い(だ)」.

> 「XがY**を**嫌う」 "X hates/dislikes Y"
> 「XはY**が**嫌いだ」
> cf.
> 「XがY**を**[好]{この}む/[好]{す}く」
> 「XはY**が**好きだ」