# What's the difference between が and を here?

Tags: adjectives, particle-が, particle-を

What is the difference between using が　and を here?

> あなたは私のこと**を**好きですか？
>
> あなたは私のこと**が**好きですか？

I've never seen the structure `nounをadjective` before.

Comment: There is a large gray area for this matter. But according to a survey younger people tend to tolerate the first sentence more.

Comment: I read both of those questions. In this case, would the first sentence, if expanded, be: "あなたは私のことを好きだと思いますか？"

Comment: Hmm, these are both simply "Do you like me?" and looks equally fine to me. Some may say the former is unnatural, though. I don't know why, but あなたは私のことを好きですか seems acceptable to me, while あなたは私のことを好きです seems less natural.

Comment: Oh really? That's interesting you say that. Other people told me as well　を is not natural but acceptable. Interesting. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> あなたは私のこと**を**好きですか？
>   あなたは私のこと**が**好きですか？

In general, the sentence with 「が」 is correct. But you couldn't say the other one is incorrect.

I'll show you an example where 「あなたは私のこと**を**好きですか？」 is more natural than 「あなたは私のこと**が**好きですか？」.

The example is as follows:

> She asked "あなたは私のこと**を**どう思うのですか？　あなたは私のこと**を**好きですか？　それとも嫌いですか？"

In this sentence the phrase 「あなたは私のこと**を**好き」 means 「あなたは私のこと**を**好きと思う」. This comprehension is well described in the Answer by user458 at the site [を vs が with use against 好き?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/%e3%82%92-vs-%e3%81%8c-with-use-against-%e5%a5%bd%e3%81%8d)