# を好き instead of が好き

Tags: grammar, particle-が, particle-を

I saw this dialogue in an anime; 柑菜{かんな} is a girl in love with 海{かい}, and a short before this happened visited 海's house. A knows of 柑菜 feelings, since there was a dialogue in which she kinda confirmed (something like "Since when do you know about my feelings?") and she explicitely said she won't confess.

> A: 柑菜な
>
> 海: 谷川{たにがわ}柑菜?谷川柑菜なら今日うちに
>
> A: あいつ海がすきだぜ。谷川柑菜は霧島海人{きりしまかいと}を好きなんだ

I'm not sure why 「を」 instead of 「が」. I found some answers on this topic, like [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26005/usage-of-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%92%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D-outside-of-embedded-clauses) and [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3473/%E3%82%92-vs-%E3%81%8C-with-use-against-%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D), but they focus on 「好き」 and the like being in relative sentences, which doesn't seem the case here. Does using 「を」 implies an unsaid 「と思う」? Since A knows about 柑菜's feelings I'm not sure this is the case.

Comment: I don't quite follow the lines even with your description. Did you transcribe correctly?

Comment: I forgot a 菜 in the second line, but the rest should be right; I added that 海 is B's name (sorry I forgot to mention it before, not sure why I used "B" instead of his name in my description). The second line I think means 「今日うちに来ました」, since Kanna went to Kai home that day. Does it make more sense?

Comment: Doesn't [my question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/26005/usage-of-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%92%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D-outside-of-embedded-clauses) cover the cases where 好き is used outside relative clauses?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something? From what I understand from your question, beside relative clauses「を」 is ok when there is an outside verb (like 「思う」); maybe it's because is a question sentence, as briefly explained in the accepted answer? In the comments Darius said that suspects "a が-marked argument is required in the question for the を-marked objects to sound natural", but in my case there is no 「が」, so not I'm not sure if that's the case.

Comment: I have to say my answer over there doesn’t fully explain this question. My take on this one is that it has to do with “scope” of the なんだ (emphasis) going around the topic vs not. If you say 君が好きなんだ！ it is almost definitely 私は — “*I* like you!”, but 君を好きなんだ！ seems to make まるまるが “*They* like you” far more possible. Somehow this has to do with the emphasis, but I can’t seem to yet come up with a full explanation...

Comment: @Mauro btw I feel the same way as this answer https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/27371/7810 to that question...

Comment: If you think it's a duplicate I can edit the question to link that answer and point at Darius' comment here and we can close this?